# Erlang JInterface: OtpNode vs OtpSelf

Tags: erlang, jinterface

I'm studying the [Erlang JInterface package](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/jinterface_users_guide.html), and I'm not clear on the difference between the [OtpNode class](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/java/com/ericsson/otp/erlang/OtpNode.html) and the [OtpSelf class](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/java/com/ericsson/otp/erlang/OtpSelf.html) and how they're intended to be used.

Comment: Have you read http://erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/java/com/ericsson/otp/erlang/OtpSelf.html and http://erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/java/com/ericsson/otp/erlang/OtpNode.html?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main difference is:

> This class is used when you do not wish to manage connections
>   yourself - outgoing connections are established as needed, and
>   incoming connections accepted automatically.

`OtpNode` is oriented towards managing the connections yourself.